# Linux Rename command uppercase first letter

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, rename

I'm writing a Bash script for cleaning up in my music.

I wanted it to format all the file names and making them and so with a little internet search I wrote this line:

```
sed -i -e 's/[-_]/ /g' -e 's/ \+/ /g' -e **'s/\<[a-z]/\U&/g'** -e "s/$artist //g" -e "s/$album //g"
```

Which I used to add the file names to a text file and then sed it, but then I didn't know how to apply the new names to the files.

So then I started experimenting with rename and managed to get the exact same result
except for the bolded parts, which is supposed to make every first letter in a word uppercase.

```
rename 's/[-_]/ /g' * && rename 's/\s+/ /g' * && **rename 's/\s\w{1}/*A-Z*/g' *** && rename 's/^\d+[[:punct:]]\s//g' * && rename "s/$artist\s//g" * && rename "s/$album\s//g" * && rename "s/($ext)//g" *
```

Now, the code in rename is working (satisfactorily at least), finding only one letter after a SPACE character, but it's the replacement that is problematic. I've tried numerous different approaches, all leaving me with the result that the first letter in focus get exchanged to exactly A-Z in this case.

In the rename manual page it says to make lower case uppercase you do 's/a-z/A-Z/g' but it's easy to figure that it only applies when it finds a-z A-Z.
So this is what I need help with.

A bonus would be if someone knows how to do it like in the sed example, where the \< matches the beginning of each word, because at the moment, my rename command won't apply to the very first word and neither will it apply if there are multiple discs looking like "Disc name [Disc 1]" for obvious reasons.

Comment: I notice you keep "signing off" on your posts. [Don't do that.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)

Comment: If you have a text file with source name and destination name pairs already, `sed 's/^/mv /' textfile | sh` is all you need (although quoting file names with spaces etc complicates things; this is just a proof of concept, not an actual answer).

Answer (score 15):

This is sort-of a Perl question, since `rename` is written in Perl, and instructions for how to perform the renaming are a Perl command.

In a `s///` in order for the substitution to know which letter to insert the upper-case version of, it has to ‘capture’ the letter from the input. Parentheses in the pattern do this, storing the captured letter in the variable `$1`. And `\u` in a substitution makes the next character upper-case.

So you can do:

```
$ rename 's/\s(\w)/ \u$1/g' *
```

Note that the replacement part has to insert a space before the upper-case letter, because the pattern includes a space and so both the space and the original letter are being replaced. You can avoid this by using `\b`, a zero-width assertion which only matches at a word boundary:

```
$ rename 's/\b(\w)/\u$1/g' *
```

Also you don't need the `{1}` in there, because `\w` (like other symbols in regexs) matches a single character by default.

Finally, the example in *rename(1)* is actually `y/A-Z/a-z/`, using the `y///` operator, not `s///`. `y///` is a completely different operator, which replaces all occurrences of one set of letters with another; that isn't of use to you here, where it's only some characters you want making upper-case.

Comment: Thanks for this thorough explanation. It helped me massively in achieving my goal. I redid my whole substitution formula and ended up with rename 's/(\w)(\w{1,})/\u$1$2/g' *, which looks for a letter and captures it in $1, IF and only if that letter is followed by at least one other letter, and then it capitalizes $1 and prints the rest of the word out using $2. I had some problems figuring this out, with the \b boundary and read that it wouldn't match two alphabetical characters after each other, but \B did, although that didn't work either... I'm not sure exactly why at this point.

Comment: ‘1 or more’ is a common requirement, so has its own symbol, `+`. You can write `\w+` instead of `\w{1,}`.

Comment: `\b` matches at the transition from a word character to a non-word character (or vice versa). `\B` is the opposite, matching anywhere else. So `/\b\w\B/` matches a word character which must not have a word character before it but does have a word character after it. Meaning `s/\b(\w)\B/\u$1/g` has the same effect as your formula, but doesn't bother taking out the second and subsequent characters of words just to put them back in again.

Comment: Ahh I see. I tried doing `(\w)\B\w+`, but that ended up capitalizing the first letter, and remove all other, but I understand now that `\B` doesn't need anything after for it to work. It matches all it was made to match if I understand that correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's right. `\B` simply means ‘this point in the string must be between two word characters’ (or between two non-word characters, but the `\w` before it precludes that in your case).

Comment: In my Archlinux machine, the `rename` command is part of the `util-linux` package and it is dumb simple, It just gets 2 arguments like `mv` and it doesn't support regex at all. I don't know if all distros are like that these days but The solutions by @Perleone and @Smylers won't work on my machine.

Comment: @DoronBehar: Yeah, there are some competing `rename` commands around. The original poster of this question clearly had the one which takes a Perl expression. Arch may have it under a different name, such as `prename`. Or you can install the [File::Rename Perl module](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/File-Rename/rename.PL) to get it. Debian has [some history of `rename` commands](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=735134#5).

Answer (score 4):

```
rename -nv 's{ (\A|\s) (\w+) }{$1\u$2}xmsg'
```

This looks for the beginning of the string `\A` or for whitespace `\s` followed by at least one or more word characters (a-z, 0-9, underscore) `\w+`. It will uppercase the first character of all word sequences.